# How to pass Azure AppSettings to NodeJS App running on Linux AppService

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

I am running a nestJS app on an Azure Linux AppService. I have added Application Settings within the appService, but I can't seem to get the app to pull through the value.

one of the appSettings is `process.env.DB_Host` with value `mysqlserveraddress` but when the app starts it says it cannot connect to `process.env.DB_Host` rather than the `mysqlserveraddress`

How do I pass these values in?

Thanks

Tommy

Comment: Can you paste a code snippet with the lines where you're reading `process.env.DB_Host` and any other context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using below code to check the `Environment Variable` in my Linux App Service.

[image]

I can see the entire `Environment variables` which is available in my Linux App Service.

And same I had added my `App Settings` in my Linux App Service.

[image]

[image]

Now I am specifically get the `AppSettings` Value in `App.js` and deployed in `App Serive`.

[image]

Now, I can get the `Environments variable`.

[image]